# How to delete row from sqlite at listview Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a listview and i am getting the data from sqlite database. My problem is to delete a row which user selected it from listview. I can delete all table by

dbConn.delete("Restobj", null,null);

But i cant delete a single row which is selected from listview.

Please Help

Answer (score 3):

You essentially need to get the row id from the selected ListView item. Using the row id you can easily delete that row:

```
String where = "_id = " + _id;
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, null);
```

After deleting the row item make sure you get the ListView adapter cursor and do a **requery**.  If you don't you will not see the updated table, hence updated ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of those other two parameters to the delete method.  Take a look at the API documentation for more information.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Pass in something other than null.

Also, try searching on stackoverflow and/or Google for this topic.  The answers are plentiful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the appropriate values to the database object.  I'm assuming that dbConn is an instance of a database object.  If that is the case, you can pass in dbConn.delete() with 3 arguments.  The first argument is the table name.  The second is the whereClause.  This is something similar to:

```
"id = " + objectDatabaseId
```

The final variable in this case you can leave blank.  The end result is something like:

```
String whereClause = "id = " + objectDatabaseId;
dbConn.delete("Restobj", whereClause, null);
```

As a side note, it's better to use constants when referring to table names and table columns as apposed to "Restobj" you should have something like RestObject.TABLE_NAME where the constant is defined as a static final String inside of the RestObject.

-Randall